# how to trigger breakpoint by command in matlab

Tags: matlab, breakpoints

I have an `if` state in my code where if something went wrong and I want to debug if it hits there. similar to manually set breakpoint  [image] on that line but permanent.
so it will always have that red dot over there by command..

I've seen some `dbstop` commands but they are all ends with `in file` or `if error`..

I couldn't find a basic `'dbstop here'` or something..

Is that possible?
Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Take a look at the `keyboard` command. It will not create the red dot, but it basically behaves like a breakpoint.

Comment: Pretty neat, but a distracting name for me. That's exactly like a breakpoint to enter the debug mode. They could almost have called the command `dbstart` or something closer to the family of commands it belongs to (_associated commands are_ `dbcont` _and_ `dbquit`)

Answer (score 4):

[`dbstop`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dbstop.html) has more arguments than just `in file` or `if error`:

> `dbstop in file at location` sets a breakpoint at the specified location. MATLAB execution pauses immediately before that location, unless the location is an anonymous function. If the location is an anonymous function, then execution pauses just after the breakpoint.

Comment: Nice one. But since you're quoting the documentation, why not include the [`dbstop in [file] at [location] if [expression]`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dbstop.html?refresh=true#buznbn3) expression. Which could also take care of his `if` statement (_in case it is only there for debugging purpose and not to actually change the code flow_).